# Trouble downloading .tar in R

Tags: r, download, tar

I have written code that builds a URL to download files from a certain website.
When I paste it into the browser, it immediately downloads the necessary files, as a tar folder (.tar) which I then easily unzip.
I need it to do that from within the code in R.

I have looked into several functions for downloading in R, and almost all of them seemingly work, but then when I try to unzip it (manually, to check what's wrong), I get a message that says: "The archive is corrupt".

I have tried it using file.download, curl_download, and others.

Using file.download, I get the error:

> ```
> H:\R\tempVNC.tar: Checksum error in H:\R\gdc_download_20180222_120441.tar. The file is corrupt
> ```

Using curl_download, I once got the error:

> Error in curl_download(data, destfile = vncZipPath, quiet = FALSE, mode = "w") : HTTP error 500.

And when I try to unzip the file I always get the error:

> ```
> H:\VNC Files\vnc.tar.gz: The archive is corrupt
> ```

I have tried so many options that I do not remember them all. But nothing seems to work. (Again, the URL I wrote certainly does do the job when pasted into a browser. The problem is with sending it from R.)

I would appreciate any advice in the matter.

Thanks in advance,

M

This is the URL for downloading the files:

> https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/10895295-0a9d-414b-a367-24d29f1bd898,696c51da-f166-4dbb-8ba2-e6ecc11a7ccd,6b4f0ea1-3884-45e4-994e-3ebc1c76c2a1,7c7ceb7e-25be-4056-bcea-3ef319d42342,2f22c96a-7b69-4e9c-96ac-be58fc2a79f1,3fcc165a-500b-4a2e-99d8-911448fe57d2,38d7d00a-594d-4bdc-a34c-660bfc195ff0,14a97b71-eb7c-4e3c-bdf6-dd310daa8337,c37cfb04-f560-4cc9-bcec-666300cc93d6,5c31c14c-6d61-4097-bef1-fd99aa1d9e3d,e02c3f8a-88fc-479a-9827-682c16581313,4e376dc4-d851-480e-a21c-bd30405a7274?related_files=false

(I have shortened it by removing some of the file IDs, so that it shouldn't be too long...)

The relevant part of my code is:

```
my_url <- "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/10895295-0a9d-414b-a367-24d29f1bd898,696c51da-f166-4dbb-8ba2-e6ecc11a7ccd,6b4f0ea1-3884-45e4-994e-3ebc1c76c2a1,7c7ceb7e-25be-4056-bcea-3ef319d42342,2f22c96a-7b69-4e9c-96ac-be58fc2a79f1,3fcc165a-500b-4a2e-99d8-911448fe57d2,38d7d00a-594d-4bdc-a34c-660bfc195ff0,14a97b71-eb7c-4e3c-bdf6-dd310daa8337,c37cfb04-f560-4cc9-bcec-666300cc93d6,5c31c14c-6d61-4097-bef1-fd99aa1d9e3d,e02c3f8a-88fc-479a-9827-682c16581313,4e376dc4-d851-480e-a21c-bd30405a7274?related_files=false"
vncTar <- paste(getwd(), "vnc.tar", sep = "//") # Create destination file
a <- curl_download(my_url, destfile = vncTar, quiet = TRUE, mode = "w")
download.file(my_url, destfile = vncTar, method = 'libcurl') #tried several "methods", including default...
dir.create("Extracted Files")
untar(vncTar, "Extracted Files")

# I also tried the following, using Rcurl package:
f = CFILE(vncTar, mode="wb")
curlPerform(url = my_url, writedata = f@ref)
close(f)
#The error this gave is:
#Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake 
#failure
```

Update:
Thanks to @Spacedman for getting it to work! I had tried many suggestions I had found online but none worked properly. This is the code that worked perfectly, thanks to @Spacedman:

```
my_url <- "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/10895295-0a9d-414b-a367-24d29f1bd898,696c51da-f166-4dbb-8ba2-e6ecc11a7ccd,6b4f0ea1-3884-45e4-994e-3ebc1c76c2a1,7c7ceb7e-25be-4056-bcea-3ef319d42342,2f22c96a-7b69-4e9c-96ac-be58fc2a79f1,3fcc165a-500b-4a2e-99d8-911448fe57d2,38d7d00a-594d-4bdc-a34c-660bfc195ff0,14a97b71-eb7c-4e3c-bdf6-dd310daa8337,c37cfb04-f560-4cc9-bcec-666300cc93d6,5c31c14c-6d61-4097-bef1-fd99aa1d9e3d,e02c3f8a-88fc-479a-9827-682c16581313,4e376dc4-d851-480e-a21c-bd30405a7274?related_files=false"
vncTar <- paste(getwd(), "vnc.tar", sep = "//") # Create destination file name
download.file(my_url, vncTar, mode = "wb") 
files <- untar(vncTar, compress=TRUE, list=TRUE) # Saves list of file names
untar(vncTar, compress=TRUE) # Extracts the files
```

Comment: It is a binary file. You should use `mode = "wb"`.

Comment: Are you confusing "zipped" files (extension usually .zip) with compressed tar ball files (extension .tar.gz). You need *different* tools to extract them and if you try extracting one with the wrong tool it is likely to report the file is corrupted.

Comment: [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a free utility that can extract both zip and tar files, see this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/80019/how-can-i-unzip-a-tar-gz-in-one-step-using-7-zip)

Comment: @djhurio It is not binary files, but text files.

Comment: @Spacedman I am not confusing them, I mistakenly wrote "zip" above instead of tarball, but I made it very clear that I am talking about .tar. In any case, the issue is with downloading it, the "untar" function works fine with the files I download manually, but the issue is with actually downloading the file via R. That's where the problem is...

Comment: @OdeToMyFiddle Thanks but apparently you didn't read my question. I wrote it works fine manually, but the problem is with downloading the files from an R script. Once the proper thing is unloaded I untar it from R and that works fine.

Comment: @MI, gziped file is a binary file. From the gzip home page: "99.9% of the problems with gzip are due to file transfers done in ASCII mode instead of BINARY mode." http://www.gzip.org/

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible. Rewrite it like: `url="http:/...." ; d=tempfile() ; download.file(url, d) ; untar(d, compressed=TRUE, list=TRUE)`

Comment: @Spacedman, I edited it like you said. It still doesn't work...

Comment: Your code is wrong. You've set a variable called `vncZipPath` but downloaded using a *filename* of `vncZipPath` - creating a file called "vncZipPath": `download.file(url, destfile = "vncZipPath"``. Fix your code.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, well spotted. That was by mistake, but in all the other tries it wasn't like that and it still made the problem. I really appreciate your taking the time to help me. I have a feeling we are almost there.... Thanks! I'd be happy to hear what you think is still the problem now...

Comment: I would appreciate understanding why my question was voted down. It would help me to understand what is wrong with it so that I can know for future times. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me - cut and paste these four functions into an R session and if it works, great, if it doesn't then edit your question *to include just these four lines* and show the error messages:

```
my_url <- "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/data/10895295-0a9d-414b-a367-24d29f1bd898,696c51da-f166-4dbb-8ba2-e6ecc11a7ccd,6b4f0ea1-3884-45e4-994e-3ebc1c76c2a1,7c7ceb7e-25be-4056-bcea-3ef319d42342,2f22c96a-7b69-4e9c-96ac-be58fc2a79f1,3fcc165a-500b-4a2e-99d8-911448fe57d2,38d7d00a-594d-4bdc-a34c-660bfc195ff0,14a97b71-eb7c-4e3c-bdf6-dd310daa8337,c37cfb04-f560-4cc9-bcec-666300cc93d6,5c31c14c-6d61-4097-bef1-fd99aa1d9e3d,e02c3f8a-88fc-479a-9827-682c16581313,4e376dc4-d851-480e-a21c-bd30405a7274?related_files=false"

d = tempfile()
download.file(my_url, d, mode="wb")
untar(d, compress=TRUE, list=TRUE)
# [1] "MANIFEST.txt"
```

This is about the simplest way of downloading and extracting a tar file in R, and is what your question should look like.

If this works, you should have a file that exists and is this big (although Ive seen some variation in the file size...):

```
file.exists(d)
## [1] TRUE
file.size(d)
## [1] 32654
```

To extract the files to the current directory, take out `list=TRUE`:

Anything there?

```
file.exists("MANIFEST.txt")
## [1] FALSE
```

No. Download and `untar`:

```
d = tempfile()
download.file(my_url, d, mode="wb")
untar(d, compress=TRUE)
```

Nothing *seems* to happen, but:

```
file.exists("MANIFEST.txt")
## [1] TRUE
```

a file appears. All the stuff appears:

```
> list.files(".")
 [1] "10895295-0a9d-414b-a367-24d29f1bd898"
 [2] "14a97b71-eb7c-4e3c-bdf6-dd310daa8337"
 [3] "2f22c96a-7b69-4e9c-96ac-be58fc2a79f1"
 [4] "38d7d00a-594d-4bdc-a34c-660bfc195ff0"
 [5] "3fcc165a-500b-4a2e-99d8-911448fe57d2"
 [6] "4e376dc4-d851-480e-a21c-bd30405a7274"
 [7] "5c31c14c-6d61-4097-bef1-fd99aa1d9e3d"
 [8] "696c51da-f166-4dbb-8ba2-e6ecc11a7ccd"
 [9] "6b4f0ea1-3884-45e4-994e-3ebc1c76c2a1"
[10] "7c7ceb7e-25be-4056-bcea-3ef319d42342"
[11] "c37cfb04-f560-4cc9-bcec-666300cc93d6"
[12] "e02c3f8a-88fc-479a-9827-682c16581313"
[13] "MANIFEST.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks! I run it and it does download the file, but not as a tar.gz, rather an unidentified file type. Then, when I run the untar() line, I get the following error: "Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) : incomplete block on file". Do you know why that might be? Thanks!

Comment: "unidentified file type" according to what? It won't be named .tar.gz but that doesn't affect the data on the disk.

Comment: But the untar() function gives the error I wrote here... (in my above comment)... So it doesn't open...

Comment: Try again with `mode="wb"` (see edit) and check existence and size (see edit)

Comment: That is why I wrote in my code a filename ending in .tar (tried it also with ending in .tar.gz). The problem is, when I try to extract it (manually so far, since untar() has an error), I get an error: "H:\vnc.tar: Checksum error in H:\gdc_download_20180222_163256.tar. The file is corrupt". Note that the long file name that is mentioned in the error is in fact the name I would like the file to have once it is downloaded.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly now, with the changes you suggested. Thank you! I had tried something similar but kept having lots of errors. I looked up many options online and ran them, but none did it. In case it helps anyone in the future, these were the changes which you suggested which made it work (which I hadn't tried after digging online): 1. add 'mode=wb' in the download.file() function. 2. Add 'compress=TRUE' & 'list=TRUE' in the untar() function. 3. Remove extras which I had added following many searches online for a solution. Thank you so much, I appreciate your time, patience & help!

Comment: Oops, just one more thing... Untar gives me a list of file names, but it still seems compressed. I saved the list returned from untar() as "vnc", and when I run 'file.exists(vnc[5])', it says FALSE. Individual files also don't appear in the folder. What can I do about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least I know the download worked properly, because I can manually extract the files. However, the above extraction (untar()) does not properly do the job. It gives me a list of file names included, but file.exists() function returns FALSE for those file names and they do not appear in the folder. Any idea how to solve that? Thanks!!

Comment: `untar` lists the files because I put `list=TRUE` in the argument. Take that out (and leave `compress=TRUE`) and it will extract them. I was trying to make sure we could see if the file was not corrupt.

Comment: Thanks. I took it out and then it doesn't seem to do anything... It is helpful to me to have a list of the file names, but I need to also have access to the files themselves and I don't... It doesn't give me any error message, just nothing seems to happen. I checked in the folder, it is identical to before running the untar() function...

Comment: Nothing **seems** to happen but in actuality the tar is extracted. See edits.

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly now!! Thank you ever so much for your time, patience and clear explanations!